# Table export with custom filename

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, excel

How can I get the custom filename when exporting to Excel? I am using given jQuery to export. Thanks fro help.

```html
<html>
<input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('export', 'sheetname')" value="Export to Excel">
<script type="text/javascript">
  var tableToExcel = (function() {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
      template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
      base64 = function(s) {
        return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
      },
      format = function(s, c) {
        return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {
          return c[p];
        })
      }
    return function(table, name) {
      if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
      var ctx = {
        worksheet: name || 'Worksheet',
        table: table.innerHTML
      }
      window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
    }
  })()
</script>
<html>
```

Comment: Just FYI, using all capital letters is considered rude because it's interpreted as shouting. I've edited the question for you

Comment: Thanks I keep that in Mind Next Time @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use ExcellentExport.js, the library deals with all these problems and conversions.

https://github.com/jmaister/excellentexport